# Vue 3 can we bind a property of parent's model?

Tags: vuejs3

For example in below code:

```
<el-form ref="userFormRef" :model="filters" label-width="80px">
    <el-form-item label="名称:" prop="name">
      <el-col :span="6">
        <el-select v-model="filters.name.op" value-key="key" placeholder="请选择" @change="opChange(filters.name)">
          <el-option v-for="item in filters.name.ops" :key="item.key" :label="item.label" :value="item" />
        </el-select>
      </el-col>
      <el-col :span="2" class="text-center">
        <span class="text-gray-500">-</span>
      </el-col>
      <el-col :span="13">
        <el-input v-model="filters.name.value" />
      </el-col>
    </el-form-item>
     ...
</el-form>
```

the form was already bind to a object called `filters`, and filters has properties like below:

```
const filters = reactive<UserFilter>({
  name: {
    op: FilterOperator.EQUAL,
    ops: StringFilterOperators,
    value: undefined,
  },
  manageGroup: {
    op: FilterOperator.EQUAL,
    ops: DictFilterOperators,
    value: undefined,
  },
  userType: {
    op: FilterOperator.EQUAL,
    ops: DictFilterOperators,
    value: undefined,
  },
  userStatus: {
    op: FilterOperator.EQUAL,
    ops: DictFilterOperators,
    value: undefined,
  }
});
```

to bind the select in the first form item to the `name.op` of `filters`, I am currently using `v-model="filters.name.op"`.

is there any feature can shorten the expression ?

just like this:

```
filters -> form 
filters.name -> form item
filters.name.op -> select in form item
```

in **imaginary pseudo code**:

```
<el-form ref="userFormRef" :model="filters" label-width="80px">
    <el-form-item label="名称:" model="name">
      <el-col :span="6">
        <el-select v-model="op" value-key="key" placeholder="请选择" @change="opChange(filters.name)">
          <el-option v-for="item in ops" :key="item.key" :label="item.label" :value="item" />
        </el-select>
      </el-col>
      <el-col :span="2" class="text-center">
        <span class="text-gray-500">-</span>
      </el-col>
      <el-col :span="13">
        <el-input v-model="value" />
      </el-col>
    </el-form-item>
     ...
</el-form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. You are talking about JS magic like `with`. It's deprecated for various reason like variable name conflicts.

You can though have something

```
<el-option name="`name.op[${index}]`" />
<el-input name="name.value" />
```

But for that you should change the code of `<el-option>`. In my project I use that with `registerInput()` function which creates `v-model` on the calling component with proper binding to the form data. It's quite complex. Usually this design is called a form constructor.